Import requests in Azure Function Serverless
Hi I have a code with python that I need to execute it with an azure function, the thing is that it does not work because it says that it is not installed requests, I know that I need to use a requirements.txt to install it but how can I use it if I am using the option that it is serverless, How could I execute this code?
import logging
import requests

from azure.functions import TimerRequest
from datetime import datetime, timezone


def main(mytimer: TimerRequest) -> None:
utc_timestamp = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).isoformat()

if mytimer.past_due:
    logging.info('The timer is past due!')

url = "https://test.com/dtes/1"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

It shows: Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'.
What do I need to do to fix the issue?
Thanks


Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'.

To resolve the issue ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' in your Azure Function, you'll need to ensure that the requests library is available within your function's environment.

Since you are using Azure Functions in a serverless context typically handle this by specifying the required dependencies in a requirements.txt file.

I have added the requests library in requirements.txt and installed the requirement.txt by using pip install -r requirements.txt  command.
The below function code ran successfully.
import logging
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import azure.functions as func

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    url = "http://localhost:8000/"
    headers = {}

    try:
        # Make GET request to the specified URL
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Parse JSON data from the response
            json_data = response.json()
            
            # Iterate over each item in the JSON array
            for item in json_data:
                item_id = item.get('id')
                item_name = item.get('name')
                item_price = item.get('price')
                
                # Log details of each item
                logging.info(f"Item ID: {item_id}, Name: {item_name}, Price: ${item_price:.2f}")

        else:
            logging.error(f"HTTP GET request failed with status code: {response.status_code}")

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred during HTTP GET request: {str(e)}")

    except ValueError as e:
        logging.error(f"Error parsing JSON response: {str(e)}")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}")

I am able to get payload response. check below:
Output:

